# The use of "stand" or "stand up" in context

Tags: difference, adverbs

Tell me plese if the use of *up* is optional in the following context.

> I have been **standing** (**up**) in line for three hours.

In one of English textbooks they use *up*, but what does it add to the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

"Standing in line" is an idiom. I don't recall ever encountering "standing **up** in line." It sounds very odd. I have dreamt up a context in which someone might produce it: they mean to convey that they've been on their feet for a long time. But even so, that's not a good way to express that.